# Can I use a hyphen or a dash instead of camelCase for i18next keys?

Tags: javascript, json, internationalization, i18next

For i18n purposes I'm storing and using a lot of keys and I find using a dash is more readable. I've noticed that all the examples for i18next use camelCase for keys and it appears that _ underscore is reserved for plurals and context.

My question is, is it allowed to use hyphens or dashes in keys for i18next? Or are they also reserved for some other purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only keys you can't use with default settings are

`:` which separates namespace (https://www.i18next.com/essentials.html#accessing-keys-in-different-namespaces)

and

`.` which nests in json (https://www.i18next.com/essentials.html#accessing-keys).

both can be overridden: https://www.i18next.com/configuration-options.html#misc -> keySeparator, nsSeparator

no need for camelCase or not using `_`

Comment: Hmm, but isn't underscore used as a separator for plurals or other context? Or is i18next smart enough to distinguish?

Comment: All links to docs are broken here as of November 2023.